# making a link class

Tags: css, class, hyperlink

I've made a website that I want to make with styled links. I don't want to set a generalized style for all of the links. I want to make different classes for them.

I've tried doing this on a tester page, and I can't get it to work. 
Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
test: link {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #C00;
}
test: hover {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #6F0;
}
test: active {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #90F;
}
test: visited {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #FF0;
}
.test {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
    color: #999;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
Emily

<p>sdlkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjlsdkf
sdlkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjlsdkf
sdlkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjlsdkf
sdlkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjlsdkf

  <span class="test"><a href="http://www.ehow.com/how_2080242_style-link-css.html">rose</a> 

  <a href="http://www.ehow.com/how_2080242_style-link-css.html"> daisy</a> 

  <a href="http://www.ehow.com/how_2080242_style-link-css.html">tulip</a> 

  <a href="http://www.ehow.com/how_2080242_style-link-css.html"> cactus</a> </span>
<p>ldkfjsldkfjlsdkfsdlkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjs    ldkfjsldkfjlsdkfsdlkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsld



</body>
</html>
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Few things wrong here. Test is a class, which means it needs to be preceeded by a period - `.test`. Second, the links are in the test span. So you should have `.test a` to indicate a link in the test span. Lastly, you need to put the link tag `a` just before the semi-colon. No space.

http://jsfiddle.net/vPBCB/

```
.test a:link {
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #C00;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, But it still isn't working. Here is some code:              .test a: link {
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1em;
 color: #C00;
}  <a href="http://www.ehow.com/how_2080242_style-link-css.html" class=".test"> daisy</a>

Comment: The `.` does not go in the class name. It only goes in the style sheet. `class="test"`, not `"class=".test"`

Comment: And I also changed:   <a href="ehow.com/how_2080242_style-link-css.html"; class=".test"> daisy</a>                     A I took out the period before:   class=".test"    So now it's class="test"

Comment: And it still doesn't work.

Comment: You have a semi-colon after one of your quotes. You have class test on the link whereas in your original question it was on a span. To be frank, you have no idea what you are doing and SO isn't so that I do your work for you. You need to try and understand how this stuff works. Sorry, but I won't be helping you out further on this.

Comment: I am only trying to learn.

Comment: The answer mrtsherman gave me, did not solve my problem.